# SQL to insert to a table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using the below SQL to try and put content in a textbox, to a different table. It was working until I added the text 43, and text 109 section

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_EmailsSent (AccountNumber, Email1, ID, LoggedUser, LoggedDate) 
    VALUES (' " & Me.Text8 & "', 'Sent', ' " & Me.Text109 & ", ' " & me.Text43 "');
```

Can you see the mistake? Because I cant unfortunately

Comment: Use `Debug.Print`: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570) -- you will find several errors (surplus spaces, missing quotes).

Comment: And please give your controls meaningful names, `Me.txtAccountNumber` is a lot better readable than `Me.Text8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the date and the spaces ans missing quotes:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_EmailsSent (AccountNumber, Email1, ID, LoggedUser, LoggedDate) 
VALUES ('" & Me.Text8 & "', 'Sent', '" & Me.Text109 & "', #" & Format(Me!Text43.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#);"
```

No ID:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_EmailsSent (AccountNumber, Email1, LoggedUser, LoggedDate) 
VALUES ('" & Me.Text8 & "', 'Sent', '" & Me.Text109 & "', #" & Format(Me!Text43.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#);"
```

Comment: Would this be right: DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_EmailsSent (AccountNumber, Email1, ID, LoggedUser, LoggedDate)VALUES ('" & Me.Text8 & "', 'Sent', '" & Me.Text109 & "', '" & Me.Text43 & "', #" & Format(Me!Text43.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#);"

Comment: I doubt it. It's rather that ID should be excluded as it most likely is an autonumber.